# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{e^n}{n!}}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to investigate the convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{e^n}{n!}}{n^n}$$
I used ratio test and root test to test it at first, because they can solve another series that is similar to this:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{2^n}{n!}}{n^n}$$

But I eventually found that it doesn't work, because they both result in inconclusive case ($C=1$).

Ratio test:
$$C=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e(n+1)}{(n+1)(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}=1$$

Root test:
$$C=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^\frac{1}{n}=e\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n!}{n^n})^\frac{1}{n}=e\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp{(\frac{1}{n}(\ln{\frac{1}{n}}+\ln{\frac{2}{n}}+\cdots+\ln{\frac{n}{n}}))}$$
$$=e\cdot\exp{(\int_0^1\ln{x}\,dx)}=1$$

Is there a easy (elementary?) way to test its convergence? Preferably without using stirling formula.

Comment: Without Stirling's formula: Look at your ratio test. You have $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 1$$ for all $n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, you are right. Maybe it is because my textbook states ratio test differently. It simply said $C=1$ means inconclusive.

Comment: This is not the ratio test, which as you say, is inconclusive. This says that the terms do not go to $0$.

Comment: [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says that $$ \left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{\frac{n+1}n}\ge1+\frac1n\implies\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\ge\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n $$ That is, $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is increasing. Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$, we have $$ \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le e $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio test in the form:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of (strictly) positive terms. If $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1\,,$$ then the series $\sum a_n$ converges. If $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 1$$ or there is an $n_0$ such that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geqslant 1$ for $n \geqslant n_0$, then the series diverges (since the terms don't converge to $0$). Otherwise the test is inconclusive.

yields the divergence of the series, since the terms don't converge to $0$ (because $\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigr)^n < e$ for all $n$).

The often-taught form of the ratio test that assumes the existence of $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and only considers the value of the limit isn't strong enough to decide this case.

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$
\frac{{a_{n + 1} }}
{{a_n }} = e\left( {\frac{n}
{{n + 1}}} \right)^n  > 1 \Leftrightarrow \left( {\frac{n}
{{n + 1}}} \right)^n  > e^{ - 1} 
$$
but
$$
\left( {\frac{n}
{{n + 1}}} \right)^n  > e^{ - 1}  \Leftrightarrow \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}
{n}} \right)^n  = \left( {1 + \frac{1}
{n}} \right)^n  < e
$$
which is true.
Therefore, for each $n \geq 1$ we have that $a_{n+1} >a_n$ and in this means that $a_{n} \geq a_1>0$. Therefore  the condition
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } a_n  = 0
$$
is not satisfied and the series is divergent.